# Cauchy criterion for the limit of a function

Tags: calculus

The real limit of $f(x)$ exists if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if every $x,y\in A$, $x≠y$ are $0<\left|x−a\right|<\delta$ and $0<\left|y−a\right|<\delta$ then $\left|f(x)−f(y)\right|<\varepsilon$.

If

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}$$

and $a = 0$ then

$$0<\left|x\right|<\delta, \quad 0<\left|y\right|<\delta, \quad \text{ and } \quad \left|\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3} − \frac{\sin(y)-y}{y^3}\right|<\varepsilon.$$

As

$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3} − \frac{\sin(y)-y}{y^3}\right|< \left|x-y\right|\leq \left|x\right|+\left|-y\right|=\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|<2\delta$$

holds, we may set $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ (namely $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$) such that if every $x,y\in A$ are $0<\left|x\right|<\delta$ and $0<\left|y\right|<\delta$ then

$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3} − \frac{\sin(y)-y}{y^3}\right|<\varepsilon.$$

It follows that the real limit of $f(x)$ exists.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, if you have the big inequality, then the construction of $δ$ can proceed that way. How did you prove the big inequality, $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$?

Comment: By the mean value theorem, there is a $c∈(x,y)$ such that $f(x)−f(y)=f'(c)(x−y)$. So we have that $|f(x)−f(y)|=|f'(c)(x−y)|$. As $f'(c)∈(-1,1)$, it follows that $|f(x)−f(y)|<|x−y|$.

Comment: How did you get that bound? Does that not defeat the elementary nature of the claim? You could just as well apply the extended mean value theorem to get $$\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=\frac{\cos(x_1)-1}{3x_1^2}=\frac{-\sin(x_2)}{6x_2}=\frac{-\cos(x_3)}{6}$$ to directly compute the limit. No need to show the existence of the limit indirectly via Cauchy in addition to that.